# NextJs getInitialProps() blocks routing, and makes page unresponsive

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, next.js, server-side-rendering, vercel

*nextJs: 9.0.2
react: 16.12.0*

I am routing to a dynamic route using next/link, having around 12 api calls inside getInitialProps(), the page becomes unresponsive until all the api fetching is done.

I have referred to the with-loading example and also disabled prefetch for <Link/ >, but no good.

```
    ***Page1***

<Link href={/page1/[id]} as={<props.dynamicRouteLink>}>
  <Card 
   
  />
</Link>

***Page2***

const HomePage = dynamic(() => import('components/Home'), {
    loading: () => <LoaderComponet />,
});

const Home = props => {
return (
    <div>
    <Head>
        <title>{SEO_TAGS.index.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={SEO_TAGS.index.description} />
        <meta name="keyword" content={SEO_TAGS.index.keyword} />
        <meta name="og:title" content={SEO_TAGS.index.title} />
        <meta name="og:description" content={SEO_TAGS.index.description} />
    </Head>

    <HomePage
        {...props}
    />
    </div>
);
};



Home.getInitialProps = async props => {
const {
    PROVIDER_MEDIA_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_BASIC_INFO_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_FACULTY_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_LOCATION_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_FACILITY_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_DIRECTOR_INFO_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_CONTACT_DETAILS_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_LANGUAGES_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_YEARLY_CALENDER_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_SCHEDULE_FOR_DAY_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_WORKING_DAY_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_EMERGENCY_SERVICES_API_CALL,
    PROVIDER_SCHEDULE_CHOICE_API_CALL,
    GET_USERS_CHILDREN_API_CALL,
    GET_USERS_TOUR_SCHEDULE_API_CALL,

    POST_CLICK_COUNT_API_CALL,
} = props;

PROVIDER_MEDIA_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_LOCATION_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_BASIC_INFO_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_DIRECTOR_INFO_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_SCHEDULE_CHOICE_API_CALL({ params: {} });
PROVIDER_SCHEDULE_FOR_DAY_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_WORKING_DAY_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_CONTACT_DETAILS_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_FACULTY_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_FACILITY_API_CALL();
PROVIDER_LANGUAGES_API_CALL({ params: {} });
PROVIDER_YEARLY_CALENDER_API_CALL({ params: { id } });
PROVIDER_EMERGENCY_SERVICES_API_CALL({ params: {} });
GET_USERS_CHILDREN_API_CALL();
GET_USERS_TOUR_SCHEDULE_API_CALL();


return { };
};
```

[image]

This brings down the user experience. Can anyone suggest a workaround or solution for this.

Comment: getInitialProps is not blocking anything because you're not awaiting anything in the function and immediately return an empty object. It is best you not run this on the server because nothing is done with the return value of any of the functions.

Comment: The functions are basically, Axios calls using redux-saga middleware, the returned values are dispatched to store and used to make data available to page on load for SSR purpose. I could move data fetching to useEffect of the page, but this will affect SSR of the page right ?

Comment: `the returned values are dispatched to store and used to make data available to page on load for SSR purpose.` That is not what happens, on the server getInitialProps waits for nothing and returns `{}` immediately, by the time your sagas set the state the server has already returned the initial render. Check the network tab and look at the html returned by the server and you'll see that no data is rendered.

Comment: Ok i get it, but why does the router stay on the same page waiting for api call to be done. It would be great if i could show a loading screen instead of staying on the same page waiting for api calls to complete.

Comment: Not sure how to do this with sagas as they needlessly complicate things but with thunk you could do something like `getInitialProps = async (context) { await myThunkAction(context.store.dispatch,context.store.getState)(context.query)` now getInitialProps returns a promise and next will **wait** for this promise to finish before rendering so your state will have been set.

Comment: Hey @Vishu , I am also facing the same problem. When I click on different route the JSON files is being fetched properly but my page stuck for 2-3 seconds on the same route then the page changes. Can you help me with it?